# Padding Zeros to one column in all data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of four data frames. Each data frame has the same first column person.id (unique key to each data frame) I want to pad zeros.

ISSUE:

The code runs but outputs to the Console and doesn't change the actual data frames in the list.

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
df1 <- data.frame(person.id = 3200:3214, letter = letters[1:15])
df2 <- data.frame(person.id = 4100:4114, letter = letters[8:22])
df3 <- data.frame(person.id = 4300:4314, letter = letters[10:24])
df4 <- data.frame(person.id = 5500:5514, letter = letters[5:19])
dataList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

lapply(dataList, function(i){
  i$person.id <- str_pad(i$person.id, 6, pad = "0")
})

# Console output pads the zeros (not expected): 
[[1]]
 [1] "003200" "003201" "003202" "003203" "003204" "003205" "003206" "003207" "003208"
[10] "003209" "003210" "003211" "003212" "003213" "003214"

# Data Frames in list return with no change:

> dataList[[1]]$person.id
[1] 3200 3201 3202 3203 3204 3205 3206 3207 3208 3209 3210 3211 3212 3213 3214
```

How do I apply the change to every column names person.id in every data frame in my list?

What I want is padded zeros in every data frame in my list:

```
> dataList[[1]]$person.id
 [1] 003200 003201 003202 003203 003204 003205 003206 003207 003208
[10] 003209 003210 003211 003212 003213 003214
```

Comment: You can also use `sprintf("%06d", i$person.id)` in the `lapply` instead of `str_pad`

Comment: I have used sprintf and seen how fast it is but for my dataset it is under 50,000 records and I don't need the speed increase. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the assignment to a column but  a) did not `return` the dataframes, nor b) did you assign the results to a new name. (Welcome to functional programming. Running a function on an object does not change the original object.) All you got were the names:

```
df1 <- data.frame(person.id = 3200:3214, letter = letters[1:15])
df2 <- data.frame(person.id = 4100:4114, letter = letters[8:22])
df3 <- data.frame(person.id = 4300:4314, letter = letters[10:24])
df4 <- data.frame(person.id = 5500:5514, letter = letters[5:19])
dataList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

library(stringr)
newList <- lapply(dataList, function(i){
  i$person.id <- str_pad(i$person.id, 6, pad = "0"); return(i)
})

> str(newList)
List of 4
 $ :'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ person.id: chr [1:15] "003200" "003201" "003202" "003203" ...
  ..$ letter   : Factor w/ 15 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ person.id: chr [1:15] "004100" "004101" "004102" "004103" ...
  ..$ letter   : Factor w/ 15 levels "h","i","j","k",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ person.id: chr [1:15] "004300" "004301" "004302" "004303" ...
  ..$ letter   : Factor w/ 15 levels "j","k","l","m",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ person.id: chr [1:15] "005500" "005501" "005502" "005503" ...
  ..$ letter   : Factor w/ 15 levels "e","f","g","h",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

The function you `lapply` needs to return the full data frame.  The function you used just returns the result of the assignment, which is only the values for the column, not the entire data frame.  You also need to save the result.  Here we use `transform` as the function as it modifies a data frame, and use the `person.id` argument to modify the `person.id` column (see `?transform`):

```
df.pad <- lapply(dataList, transform, person.id=str_pad(person.id, 6, pad = "0"))
```

Then, `df.pad[[1]]`: produces:

```
[[1]]
   person.id letter
1     003200      a
2     003201      b
3     003202      c
4     003203      d
5     003204      e
6     003205      f
7     003206      g
8     003207      h
9     003208      i
10    003209      j
11    003210      k
12    003211      l
13    003212      m
14    003213      n
15    003214      o
```

You need to return the data frame because `R` is not an assign-by-reference language.  Your assignments to `i` in `lapply` just modify the local copy of `i`, not the data frames in `dataList` in the global environment.  If you want `dataList` to be modified you can substitute `dataList` for `df.pad` in the above expression, which will result in `dataList` being overwritten with a new version of it containing the modified data frames.

Comment: ?transform give me a warning on programming scripts?

Warning

This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting arithmetic functions, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument transform can have unanticipated consequences.

Comment: @mtelesha, I believe that warning applies when you want to use a variable as an argument to `transform`, which we don't do here (e.g. `transform(DF, x=arg_from_my_fun)`).

Answer (score 0):

The `pad` function in the package **qdapTools** can do this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(person.id = 3200:3214, letter = letters[1:15])
df2 <- data.frame(person.id = 4100:4114, letter = letters[8:22])
df3 <- data.frame(person.id = 4300:4314, letter = letters[10:24])
df4 <- data.frame(person.id = 5500:5514, letter = letters[5:19])
dataList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

library(qdapTools)
lapply(dataList, function(x) {x[["person.id"]] <- pad(x[["person.id"]], 6);x})
```